# In deployed appengine apps, can a User's ID be longer than 64 bits?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am working on an appengine app in Go and when I tried to get an appengine `User`'s ID and convert it to a 64-bit int with this code:

```
id, err := strconv.ParseInt(user.ID, 10, 64)
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR: error executing inner: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "185804764220139124118": value out of range
```

Does this error occur on appengine IDs in deployed code as well?

Comment: `int64       the set of all signed 64-bit integers (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)` from the Go Spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ID` field of the [`User`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/reference#User) type is defined with type `string`. Just because it contains digits, there is no guarantee that it fits into an `int64`.

The Go AppengineSDK uses values that fit into `int64`, but this is not true in production environment. They are usually longer than the max value of `int64`. They are handed to you as `string`s, so treat them like that: `string`s. Nothing forces you to convert them to a number. I don't know where you got the idea to convert them to numbers, but don't do that. They are `string`s.

Note: `User.ID` is not to be mistaken with [`Key.IntID()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Key.IntID) which is defined to be of type `int64`.

Comment: System generated id's are long integers (I am using imprecisely here, I use python) not strings. See the go docs func AllocateIDs

Comment: @TimHoffman Yes, but `User.ID` is **not** a system generated id with `AllocateIDs()`.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably yes. Reading [app engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Kinds_and_identifiers), it is written that:

> The default policy generates a random sequence of unused IDs that are
>   approximately uniformly distributed. Each ID can be up to 16 decimal
>   digits long.

From [Go specs](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/) int32 is `-2147483648 through 2147483647.` which is not enough for 16 decimals, but `int64` is enough.

Comment: Definitely, not probably.

Comment: Hm, well the ID I got was even bigger than 16 digits and wouldn't fit in a 64 bit int either so that's why I'm not sure if in a deployed app I would be able to assume the IDs fit in 64 bits.

Comment: Your quote refers to numeric key ids (`Key.IntID()`). `User.ID` is not a numeric key id.